# SOAP web service reference to generic class returns nullexception

Tags: c#, web-services, generics, soap

this is my debut on stackoverflow as a writer. I'm stacked...

I have Windows Forms Application. I added ServiceReference to .wsdl web service. Everything works good but I have problem with initialize fields from generic class.

This class looks that below:

```
public partial class setHuntingGroupRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string fwSessionIdField;

    private string pbxNameField;

    private AlcHuntingGroup huntingGroupField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string fwSessionId {
        get {
            return this.fwSessionIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.fwSessionIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("fwSessionId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public string pbxName {
        get {
            return this.pbxNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.pbxNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("pbxName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=2)]
    public AlcHuntingGroup huntingGroup {
        get {
            return this.huntingGroupField;
        }
        set {
            this.huntingGroupField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("huntingGroup");
        }
    }
```

## So i have fwSessionId, pbxName and nested AlcHuntingGroup which looks:

```
   public partial class AlcHuntingGroup : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string directoryNumberField;

        private string directoryNameField;

        private AlcHuntingGroupSearchType searchTypeField;

        private string[] membersField;

        private bool unavailableAuthorizedField;

        private bool releaseAfterTimerField;

        private string overflowDirectoryNumberField;

        private int entityField;
```

(...)

## How my code works:

```
        private void btnDodajnrdohg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        SoapDemo.ServiceReference1.AlcPbxManagementPortTypeClient soap = new 
        SoapDemo.ServiceReference1.AlcPbxManagementPortTypeClient();

        setHuntingGroupRequest request = new setHuntingGroupRequest();
        setHuntingGroupResponse response = new setHuntingGroupResponse();

        request.fwSessionId = session_id;
        request.pbxName = "demooxemai42";

        try
            {

            response = soap.setHuntingGroup(request);

            this.output.Text = response.resultCode.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {

            this.output.Text = "Error in request: " + error + "\n";
            }
          }
```

In this above example I insert to request two fields. Unfortunetaly I must also insert all fields from AlcHuntingGroup class (huntingGroup is reference to this class). I tried this:

```
request.fwSessionId = session_id;
request.pbxName = "demooxemain2";
request.huntingGroup.directoryName = "Directory Name";
request.huntingGroup.directoryNumber = "1001";
request.huntingGroup.entity = 1;
//etc
```

Intellisense properly see this fields, but when I'm start debugging this code it's return me an error in line where I have `request.huntingGroup.directoryName = "Directory Name";`

**System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object**
**SoapDemo.ServiceReference1.setHuntingGroupRequest.huntingGroup.get returned null.**

How can I protect from get null value from huntingGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.huntingGroup.directoryName = "Directory Name";
```

on your code this part

```
request.huntingGroup
```

calls getter of property. You need to initialize it first or improve getter by something like this:

```
get {
        return this.huntingGroupField ?? (this.huntingGroupField = new AlcHuntingGroup());
    }
```

This approach called "lazy initialization" - **huntingGroupField** will be initialized automatically when you try to access **huntingGroup** property first time.

Comment: Thanks Man... you're the best. I edit huntingGroup with your getter and now it works fine.

Comment: How can I "set" getter with string array?

I have this field:
`[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("members", Order=3)]
public string[] members {
get {
return this.membersField;
 }
set {
this.membersField = value;
this.RaisePropertyChanged("members");
            }
 }`

When I insert it to request, f.e. 
`request.huntingGroup.members[0] = "2003"` It returns me exactly the same error. @antonnorko

Comment: @MateuszSzafraniec in case of arrays there is a bit more complex, because you really need to create array first with predefined count of elements. Or you may use List<string> instead of string[] as an alternative.